# How can I include a variable in remove() function? I'm trying to include an environment variable in the function

Tags: c, variables

I'm attempting to learn the `remove()` function in C, and I want to make a program with first gets the environmental variable with `getenv()` function, then uses it inside the code.

However, I get the error

> "too many arguments to function remove()".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* a = getenv("USERPROFILE");
    remove("%s/Desktop/remove.txt", a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Any decent text-book, tutorial or class should have mentioned [`sprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf).

Comment: `%s` is meaningful to the printf family functions only

Comment: I figured out that %s can't be used to do that, but I have no different ideas on how to do it, so I decided to ask here. Im a begginer to C (I have no more than 3 days of experience), and I only know basics for now.

Comment: As Someprogrammerdude commented, use [`sprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) to create the path name argument to pass to `remove()`. But beware of trusting user input including environment variables e,g, what if `USERPROFILE` is set to an empty string, or to the home directory of another user, or not set at all?

Comment: I'll see what I can do. Thank you!

Comment: I tried searching, but I can't really understand how I can use it to pass the variable, and how I can do that.

Comment: I did it by using `strcat()` and combining the `USERPROFILE` env variable and the /Desktop/remove.txt path, with in result gave `%USERPROFILE%/Desktop/remove.txt`. I will still try to figure out how to do it the way you provided me. Thank you all for help.

Comment: If you can print the path using `printf` (you already have the format and argument, clearly in the shown code) then you can use `sprintf` to "print" it into a character array.

Comment: Okay. If I do that, how can I use it inside the remove() function?

Comment: Now I start to question some of your *very* basic C knowledge. How would you use an array of characters as a string when calling a function? If you solved the problem using (the longer and more complicated) `strcpy` and `strcat` solution as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65826451/440558) you already have used an array of characters as a string when calling a function (more specifically you have already done it for the `remove` call).

Comment: Yeah. I think I started my attempts to write code by myself before even reading a book and just browsing a few online tutorials. I learned my lesson and will surely do more research before asking further questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply trying to combine them this should work.
I commented out some lines and put a printf so you can run it to see the result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXPATH 256

int main()
{
    //char* a = getenv("USERPROFILE");

    char* a = "userprofile";
    char path[MAXPATH];
    strcpy(path,a);
    strcat(path,"/Desktop/remove.txt");

    //remove(path);
    printf("PATH: %s",path);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I managed to figure out the same approach 10 minutes ago, I realised I could use strcat. Thank you anyways, and have a great day!

Comment: Happy you sorted it out, have a great day too.